# sass & mixins: appending a class name with no spaces

Tags: css, sass

Hello lovely stackoverflow community.  I'm a new coder, and brand new to sass & intermediate css topics.  I'm working on a site that has themes and I'm trying to customize the design of a 3rd party survey widget we are using.

Our themes are controlled via a mixin that looks like this:

```
@mixin themify() {
 // Iterate over the themes
 @each $theme-name, $theme in $themes {
   $current-theme: $theme !global;
   @if $theme-name == ‘abc’ {
     @content;
   } @else {
     .theme-#{$theme-name} & {
       @content;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The theme-name is on the body tag & inherited by every element. So can be used to target all children with ease. However, for the survey, I need to style it using a selector targeting a specific data-attribute on the body. For ex, this selector successfully allows me to target a survey element:

```
Body[data-survey-number='77777'] div#a .b {
    // styles successfully applied!
}
```

But when I want to use the themify mixin:

```
Body[data-survey-number='77777'] div#a .b {
    @include themify {
        background-color:theme-get(secondary-color);
}
```

it breaks.  I'm seeing that the sass compiles to:

```
theme-name Body[data-survey-number='77777'] div#a .b {
    // never applies to anything :(
}
```

However what works is when a selector is compiled to this (appended at the end with no space):

```
Body[data-survey-number='77777']theme-name div#a .b {
    // this works! :)
}
```

I'm wondering how I can get this.  Perhaps creating a new mixin?

I appreciate all / any thoughts.

Comment: Update! I ended up fixing this by setting a data- attribute lower down in the dom hierarchy :) But I'd love to know how to do this with sass and would appreciate any/all thoughts.

Comment: You're missing a curly bracket in the example that you say breaks, not sure if it's just a typo in your question or the answer to your issue!